# On selecting an option from combox, the entire dov moves upward.-CSS

Tags: css

I have a layout that I need to put side by side.

Th code is in Extjs but I'm trying to style this container when a values gets selected in the combo box. As in the gif:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlgKC.gif

The container is moving upwards when any selection is been made. Is there any way in CSS I can control this behavior on select and make sure it stays still and does not move on selection?

```
 addFilter: function(token, filter, op) {
                    var filterItem = Ext.create({
                        xtype: 'container',
                        height: 30,
                        cls: 'item',
                        layout: {
                            type: 'hbox',
                            align: 'middle'
                        },
                        items: [
                       this.typeCombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                          emptyText: $L('Select a filter...'),
                          store: this.menuStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                               fields: ['key', 'title'],
                               data: this.getFilterValues()
                           })
                        })  

                        }]

                    }); // end of filteritem

                    }

                },
```

CSS:

```
.item div.qx-multi-select-combo-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    left: 320px;
}
```

Any idea ? Thanks!

Comment: did you get any error messages on the console?

Comment: nope, no errors